# Struggling with a multi-variable calculus question with functions $g(x,y)=G(r,{\theta})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was doing a past multi-variable calculus paper and I got to this question:

> Consider the functions
>
> $g(x,y)=G(r,{\theta})$
>   where $x=rcos{\theta}$ and $y=rsin{\theta}$
>
> a) Show that
>    ${G_r}={g_x}cos{\theta}+{g_y}sin{\theta}$
>
> b) Calculate $G_\theta$
>
> c) Hence, show that
>   ${g_x^2}+{g_y^2}={G_r^2}+\left(\frac{G_\theta}{r}\right)^2$
>
> d) Find $G_r{_r}$ and $G_\theta{_\theta}$
>
> e) If g satisfies Laplace's equation, show that
>   ${G_r{_r}}+\frac{G_r}{r}+\frac{G_\theta{_\theta}}{r^2}=0$

I have no idea what to do to try and answer this.
Any advice/help on how to start this question and explanations on what this question's actually asking would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Comment: Do you remember that $G_r$ is a shorthand for $$\frac {\partial G}{\partial r}$$ and similarly for the other variables?

Comment: Yes I know the meaning of $G_r$ and the other similar variables, I'm just getting confused with what $g(x,y)$ and $G_(r,/theta)$ are as it says what a x and y are but it doesn't specify what the functions g and G are (unless I'm just being dim)